# How to add unit tests using Moq and xUnit in this specific scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, autofac, xunit

I have this method in my data/service layer. We are commencing the usage of xUnit and MoQ for unit testing.  We use Autofac as our IoC container.

How to set up a unit test for this method using xUnit and MoQ ? 
Request specific code illustration with usage of Fake (if needed)

```
public async Task<AddressModel> AddAddress(string useridKey, AddressModel addressModel)
{
    IAddress address = AddressConverters.ToIAddressFromAddressModel(addressModel);
    IAddress newAddress = await _userManager.AddShippingAddressAsync(userKey, address).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return AddressConverters.ToAddressModel(newAddress);
}
```

Comment: it's a little hard to tell,  from the looks of it, you just need to mock  AddShippingAddressAsync.   is _userManger acquired via autofac?

Comment: @KeithNicholas yes _userManager is acquired via AutoFac

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject a mock user manager then do something like

```
mockUserManager.Setup(arg=>arg.AddShippingAddressAsync(It.Is<string>, It.Is<IAddress>))
    .ReturnsAsync(myNewAddressWhateverYouWantToReturn);
```

I'm not 100% about xUnit async support, but it looks like it should be something like

```
[Fact]
private async Task TestAddingAddress()
{
    // inject your mock, either here on setup...

    var thingWithAdd = new Foo();  //or inject mock into constructor...
    var newAddress = await thingWithAdd.AddAddress("", new AddressModel());

    // assert something about it....
}
```

However, I have no idea what some of your functions do, or what dependencies they have, you may need to mock some more things.